# PHP/HTML/MySQL Display

Tags: php

im having trouble with my code

Here is the code:

```
<div <?php if($row['delta_marge']<0){?> class='cel_progress_bar_delta' style='width: <?php echo $progress_bar_delta;?>%'<?php }  
elseif ($row['delta_marge']>=$seuil_haut){?> class='cel_progress_bar_delta_orange' style='width: <?php echo $progress_bar_delta;?>%'<?php }  
elseif ($delta_marge<$row['delta_marge']<$seuil_haut) {?> class='cel_progress_bar_delta_yellow' style='width: <?php echo $progress_bar_delta;?>%'<?php }?>%'>
```

I'm having troube with the second "**elseif**" where i want it to be between two numbers but it doesn't work!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the value that you are checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did edit Okba's answer but as it was getting rejected, I'll add it here for some more information. This will explain how `&&` and `||` is working and how you should use it so you'll know what you're doing.

If you want to check for more then one option in your if/else-statement use: `&&`. This makes sure that the left- and right value must be true to get through your statement.

You can also use: `||`. This will check if one of both: left/right-value is true. You can see `&&` as "AND", and `||` as "OR".

**Your example**
You want to check if something is in between. So you want to check if the value is more then X and less then Y. In this case you have to use `&&` (as both have to be true).

```
elseif ($delta_marge < $row['delta_marge'] && $row['delta_marge'] > $seuil_haut) { /* Your code when it is in between. */ }
```

In this example you validate two expressions: `$delta_marge<$row['delta_marge']` and `$row['delta_marge']>$seuil_haut`. To validate both must be true as you're using `&&`. If one of them returns "false", you'll move to the next elseif/else if there's one defined.

**Example about ||**
If you want to check if expression A or expression B is true then you use || (OR). 
For example: `if(false || true) { }`. In this case the compiler first checks the first statement, which is false. In that case it'll check the second expression which is in this case true. Your statement is true as one of both is true.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Comment: No problem. Have fun coding today with this new information! :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
elseif ($delta_marge<$row['delta_marge'] && $row['delta_marge']<$seuil_haut)
```

Comment: @elianero thanks is great but accept the answer to show it (its the check).

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @Okba You should add some explanation on your answer, what you changed - and *why* it was changed. "*try this*" answers are highly discouraged!